# JNLP Already initialized, NullPointerException with icedtea6-plugin?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I have a trusted applet, and I'm getting the following behavior with OpenJDK and icedtea6-plugin:

```
Initializing JVM...
NOT IMPLEMENTED: virtual nsresult IcedTeaPluginInstance::Start()
Jar string: applets/MyApplet.jar
jars length: 1
JNLPRuntime already initialized
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.tools.JarSigner.verifyJars(JarSigner.java:192)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.verifyJars(JNLPClassLoader.java:626)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:302)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:134)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:191)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:445)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:418)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:597)
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize applet. (net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException Fatal: Initialization Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars.)
netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize applet. (net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException Fatal: Initialization Error: A fatal error occurred while trying to verify jars.)
```

The Sun JVM and plugin work fine. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an OpenJDK issue. It's supposed to be fixed in the latest version (not in repos).